# matplotlib re position legend relative to pie chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

and a pie chart like so. 
[image]
code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
labels = 'Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs'
sizes = [15, 30, 45, 10]
result = plt.pie(sizes, labels=labels )
plt.legend(result[0], sizes,  bbox_to_anchor=(0.00, 1))
plt.show()
```

This is just a demo example. But depending on the data I am using, the legend will get in the way of the pie chart.

My question: How do I position the pie chart further left, or add some padding between the pie chart and the legend.
I have spent a while googling this, but couldn't find the answer.

Thanks
Daniel

Comment: An answer to this question is given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272206/python-legend-overlaps-with-the-pie-chart/43281595