# Removing labels from pie chart moves the legend box

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to do a pie chart where I remove the labels from it. Currently I'm doing this:

```
qx = queens_tree_types.plot(ax=axes[0], kind='pie', figsize=(8,30), legend=True, 
                            autopct='%1.0f%%', pctdistance=0.9, radius=1.2)
axes[0].set_title('Queens');
```

Which gives me the following pie:

[image]

That's nice and all, but I want to remove the labels from the chart. When I try and simply do `labels=None`, I get this picture:

[image]

The initial pie chart has the location of the legends set like this:

```
qx.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(2.5, 1.05),
      ncol=2, fancybox=True, shadow=True)
```

But when I remove the labels, I can't seem to move the legend box at all. What gives?

Comment: Please post data and full compilable code (including `import` lines) for reproducible example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Legend overlaps with the pie chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272206/python-legend-overlaps-with-the-pie-chart)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider placing the legend adjacent to the pie chart,  because the default legend placement overlays over the pie on same figure. Below demonstrates with fictitious data:

**Data**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.melt(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(20, 10)), 
                          columns=['Hulkeberry Finn', 'Captain Ahab', 'Hester Prynne', 
                                   'Nick Carraway', 'Bigger Thomas', 'Scout Finch', 
                                   'Invisible Man', 'Denver',
                                   'Tom Joad', 'Edna Pontellier']),
             var_name='group')
df = df.groupby(['group']).sum()
```

**Pie Graph 1** *(with default legend overlay)*

```
from matplotlib import rc, pyplot as plt

# GENERAL STYLE SETTINGS
font = {'family' : 'arial', 'weight': 'bold', 'size': 10}
rc('font', **font); rc("figure", facecolor="white"); rc('axes', edgecolor='darkgray')

# GRAPH WITH LEGEND
qx = df.plot(kind='pie', figsize=(8,8), y='value', labels=None,
             autopct='%1.0f%%', pctdistance=0.9, radius=1.2)
plt.legend(loc="center right", fontsize=10)

plt.title('Pie Chart Demonstration', weight='bold', size=14)

plt.show()
plt.clf()
plt.close()
```

[image: Pie Chart Overlay Legend Output]

**Pie Graph 2** *(with adjacent subplot)*

```
plt.gca().axis("equal")
pie = plt.pie(df, startangle=0, autopct='%1.0f%%', pctdistance=0.9, radius=1.2)
labels=df.index.unique()
plt.title('Pie Chart Demonstration', weight='bold', size=14)
plt.legend(pie[0],labels, bbox_to_anchor=(1,0.5), loc="center right", fontsize=10, 
           bbox_transform=plt.gcf().transFigure)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.0, bottom=0.1, right=0.85)

plt.show()
plt.clf()
plt.close()
```

[image: Pie Chart Subplot Legend Output]