# add the values beside the legend and change the position of legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

Sorry for posting mistake.I'm new here.
how can i add the numbers of data beside the legend table?
Also How can I make the legend table on the side so as not to block the visibility of the chart?

Example legend table:

```
(redcolor) at=1
(bluecolor) nt=3
(purplecolor) ct=5
```

my code:

```
aaa=[1,3,5]
name='at','nt','ct'
plt.pie(aaa,labels=name)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: See [Legend overlaps with the pie chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272206/python-legend-overlaps-with-the-pie-chart)

Answer (score 0):

The comment by JohanC answers your first question. To answer your second question: if you want to add the value to the label, you should create a list of labels which have the values 'baked in.' Essentially, you want to create a list with the strings `['at = 1', 'nt = 3', 'ct = 5']`. You can do this as follows using a combination of [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), [the `zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), and [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting) (I am using [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) in this example):

```
aaa = [1, 3, 5]
name = ['at', 'nt', 'ct']
labels = [f'{n} = {v}' for n, v in zip(name, aaa)]
```

You can then feed this list to your `plt.pie` call:

```
plt.pie(aaa, labels=labels)
```